# Is it safe to remove makewhatis from /etc/cron.weekly?

Tags: cron, linux

I have a micro instance on Amazon EC2 and because of the low resources allocated to micro instances, I have an issue with one of the weekly cron, `makewhatis`. It takes a while to complete and uses a lot of CPU and while it's running, the instance is barely (if not) responding.

I tried to modify the cron to use `nice makewhatis -w` and it is slightly better but far from good enough.

Is it safe to remove this cron from /etc/cron.weekly? If not, is there something I can do to make it use less resources?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`makewhatis` is only used to create the index for `man -k`. If you never use that capability then you don't need it. If your set of man pages never changes then you only need run it once.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I guess I could run it if I need I need to rebuild man's index. Thank you!